# How to replace multiple keywords in a string with a component

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, reactjs, replace

To start off, I'm primarily an AngularJS developer and recently switched to React, and I decided to convert an angular webapp I had previously developed to a react app. Im having a bit of an issue with a component `ExpressiveText` that searches through a string for a match to a property on a list objects and inserts a component `TriggerModal` in its place that when clicked triggers a modal with more detailed information. So the properties passed into `ExpressiveTest` are: `text`, `tags`, and `tagsProperty`.

`text` is a string (i.e. `"My search string"`)

`tags` is an array of objects (i.e. `[{id: 1, name: 'my', data: {...}}, {id: 2, name: 'string', data: {...}}]`

`tagsProperty` is the name of the property to search for as a "tag" (i.e. `name`)

I followed along with [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3386) to try and formulate an idea of how to approach this. The reason I mention that I am coming from angular is because the component I had previously created simply used something like `text.replace(regex, match => <trigger-modal data={tags[i]} />)` and then used angulars `$compile` function to render components in the text. This does not seem to be possible using react. This is what I have tried inside of my `ExpressiveText` component:

```
class ExpressiveTextComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.filterText = this.filterText.bind(this);
  }
  filterText () {
    let text = this.props.text;
    this.props.tags.map(tag => {
      const regex = new RegExp(`(${tag[this.props.tagsProperty]})`, 'gi');
      let temp = text.split(regex);
      for(let i = 1; i < temp.length; i+=2){
        temp[i] = <TriggerModal data={tag} label={tag[this.props.tagsProperty]} />;
      }
      text = temp;
    });
    return text;
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.className}>{this.filterText()}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

This works for the first tag. The issue with it is that once it goes to `map` on the second tag, `text` is then an array. I tried adding in a conditional to check if `text` is an array, but then the issue becomes that the `text` array becomes nested and doesnt work on the next iteration. Im having a really hard time wrapping my mind around how to handle this. I have also tried `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` using `text.replace(...)` but that doesn't work either and just renders `[object Object]` in place of the component. Any help or advice is much appreciated, I have to say this is probably the only major issue I have come across since my switch to React, otherwise its been very straightforward.

Edit: Since I had a question asking for expected output with a given input and more clarification, what I am looking for is a component that is given this input:

`<ExpressiveText text="my text" tags={{id: 1, name: 'text'}} tagsProperty="name" />`

would render

`<div>my <TriggerModal label="text" data={...} /></div>`

with a functional `TriggerModal` component.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you add some expected output, given some input, please?

Comment: Im not sure how to better explain... given a string (`text`), the component is supposed to search for multiple keywords (objects from `tags`, using the property defined with `tagsProperty`) and replace those keywords with React components. The issue is getting the react component(s) to render. This all takes place within the `filterText` method. Does that help?

Comment: so, given this input: `<ExpressiveText text="my text" tags={{id: 1, name: 'text'}} tagsProperty="name" />`, what is expected to be rendered is essentially `<div>my <TriggerModal label="text" /></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct in my understanding of what you're trying to accomplish, this is one way to do this it. My apologies if I misunderstood your question. Also, this is pseudocode and I'll try and fill it in with real code in a bit. Sorry if this is difficult to understand, let me know and I will try to clarify

```
filterText () {
    let text = [this.props.text];

    for (let item in this.props.tags) {
        //item will be something like {id: 1, name: 'text'}

        let searchString = new RegExp(item.name, 'gi');

        //loop through text array and see if any item matches search string regex.
        while (text.some(val => val.test(searchString)) {
            //if we are here, at least one item matches the regexp
            //loop thru text array, and split any string by searchString, and insert <TriggerModal> in their place
            for (let i = text.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                //if text[i] is string and it matches regexp, then replace with nothing
                text[i].replace(searchString, "")
                //insert <trigger modal>       
                text.splice(i, 0, <TriggerModal ... />)
            } 
        //end of while loop - test again to see if search string still exists in test array
        }
    }
    return text;
  }
```

Comment: This did not work, but did inspire my solution. The issue with this is that it caused an indefinite loop that kept adding new indexes, eventually causing the page to timeout. Could have been my fault for adapting it incorrectly. See my posted solution if you want to see how I ended up solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution.

```
filterText () {

  let text = this.props.text.split(' '),
    replaceIndexes = [];

  if(this.props.tags.length > 0) {

    this.props.tags.map(tag => {

      const regex = new RegExp('(' + tag[this.props.tagsProperty] + ')', 'gi');

      for(let i = 0; i < text.length; i++){

        if(text[i].match(regex)){

          /** 
           * Pretty simple if its a one-word tag, search for the word and replace.
           * could potentially cause some mis-matched tags but the words 
           * in my usecase are pretty specific, unlikely to be used in 
           * normal dialogue.
           */
          text[i] = <TriggerModal data={tag} label={tag[this.props.tagsLabelProperty || 'name']} />;

        }else{

          // for tags with spaces, split them up.
          let tempTag = tag[this.props.tagsProperty].split(' ');

          // check for length
          if(tempTag.length > 1) {

            // we will be replacing at least 1 item in the array
            let replaceCount = 0,
              startIndex = null;

            // If the first word of tempTag matches the current index, loop through the rest of the tempTag and check to see if the next words in the text array match
            if(tempTag[0].toLowerCase() === text[i].toLowerCase()){

              startIndex = i;
              replaceCount += 1;

              // loop through temp array
              for (let j = 0; j < tempTag.length; j++) {

                if(tempTag[j].toLowerCase() === text[i+j].toLowerCase()){
                  replaceCount += 1;
                }

              }

              // Push data into replaceIndexes array to process later to prevent errors with adjusting the indexes of the text object while looping
              replaceIndexes.push({
                startIndex: startIndex,
                replaceCount: replaceCount,
                element: <TriggerModal data={tag} label={tag[this.props.tagsLabelProperty || 'name']} />
              });

            }

          }
        }
      }

    });

  }

  // Loop through each replace index object 
  replaceIndexes.forEach((rep, index) => {
    text.splice(rep.startIndex - index, rep.replaceCount, [rep.element, ', ']);
  });

  // Since we stripped out spaces, we need to put them back in the places that need them.
  return text.map(item => {
    if(typeof item === "string"){
      return item + ' ';
    }
    return item;
  });

}
```

**Edit: This is actually pretty buggy. I ended up ditching my own solution in favor of [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-string-replace)**